# SQL Server 2017 Distributed AG's manual failover

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have configured SQL Server 2017 SQL Distributed Always-ON from DC1 to DC2. Can you please review below steps for manual failover from DC1 to DC2 and vice-versa. Please add steps If i missed any steps.

Cluster1 (Production):
DC1: DB1 (Global Primary), DB2

Cluster2 (DR):
DC2: DB3 (Forwarder), DB4

**Perform Manual failover from DC1 to DC2 (make DC2 as Production and DC1 as DR):**

**Step 1: Execute below command on DC1-DB1 and DC2-DB3. Is this correct?**

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [distributedag] 
 MODIFY 
 AVAILABILITY GROUP ON
 'ag1' WITH 
  ( 
  AVAILABILITY_MODE = SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT 
  ), 
  'ag2' WITH  
  ( 
  AVAILABILITY_MODE = SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT 
  );
```

Proceed to step 2 after the availability group synchronization_state_desc is SYNCHRONIZED.

**Step 2: Execute below command on DC1-DB1. Is this correct?**

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP distributedag SET (ROLE = SECONDARY);
```

Test the failover readiness and proceed with Step 3

**Step 3: Fail over from the primary availability group to the secondary availability group. Execute below command on DC2-DB3. Is this correct?**

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP distributedag FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS;
```

**Step 4: Change back to ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT. Execute below command on DC2-DB1. Is this correct?**

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [distributedag] 
 MODIFY 
 AVAILABILITY GROUP ON
 'ag1' WITH 
  ( 
  AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT 
  ), 
  'ag2' WITH  
  ( 
  AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT 
  );
```

After executing above steps, DC2 is primary (prod) and DC1 is secondary (DR) as mentioned below. Now make DC2 as DR and DC1 as Prod (roll back)

DC2 (production): DB3 (primary global),DB4

DC1 (DR): DB1 (Forwarder), DB2

**Step 1: Execute below command on DC2-DB3 and DC1-DB1. Is this correct?**

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [distributedag] 
 MODIFY 
 AVAILABILITY GROUP ON
 'ag1' WITH 
  ( 
  AVAILABILITY_MODE = SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT 
  ), 
  'ag2' WITH  
  ( 
  AVAILABILITY_MODE = SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT 
  );
```

Proceed to step 2 after the availability group synchronization_state_desc is SYNCHRONIZED.

**Step 2: Execute below command on DC2-DB3. Is this correct?**

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP distributedag SET (ROLE = SECONDARY);
```

**Step 3: Fail over from the primary availability group to the secondary availability group. Execute below command on DC1-DB1. Is this correct?**

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP distributedag FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS;
```

**Step 4: Change back to ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT. Execute below command on DC2-DB1. Is this correct?**

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [distributedag] 
 MODIFY 
 AVAILABILITY GROUP ON
 'ag1' WITH 
  ( 
  AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT 
  ), 
  'ag2' WITH  
  ( 
  AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT 
  );
```

Comment: Have you run this in your test environment?

Comment: The steps to failover a Distributed Availability Group are outlined in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017#failover). I'd validate the syntax there and test in a non-production environment.